# get computed background color as rgb in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, computed-style

I am trying to get the RGB background color in IE using the following code:

```
function getStyle(elem, name) {
    // J/S Pro Techniques p136
    if (elem.style[name]) {
        return elem.style[name];
    } else if (elem.currentStyle) {
        return elem.currentStyle[name];
    }
    else if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
        name = name.replace(/([A-Z])/g, "-$1");
        name = name.toLowerCase();
        s = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elem, "");
        return s && s.getPropertyValue(name);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

var $b = $("<button>");
$b.css("backgroundColor", "ButtonFace");
$("body").append($b);
alert("button bg color is: "+ getStyle($b[0],"backgroundColor"));
//alerts 'buttonface'
```

this does not return an rgb color value like firefox does, it returns 'buttonface' which is useless to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been working on a cross-browser implementation of a "getStyle" function, 
my function isn't complete yet but I can help you to solve this specific problem you have with IE.

For the computed `backgroundColor`, I'm using a hack proposed in [this](http://erik.eae.net/archives/2007/07/27/18.54.15/#comment-102297) page, it uses the IE specific [`queryCommandValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536683%28VS.85%29.aspx) method to get the [`BackColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536974(VS.85).aspx) of a selection.

About the implementation you post, I would recommend to check first if the standard `getComputedStyle` method via the `document.defaultView` exists, because some browsers like Opera, provide the IE specific `currentStyle` object for compatibility.

So I've refactored your function and included the *IE hack*:

```
function getStyle(elem, name) {
  if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
    name = name.replace(/([A-Z])/g, "-$1");
    name = name.toLowerCase();
    s = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elem, "");
    return s && s.getPropertyValue(name);
  } else if (elem.currentStyle) {
    if (/backgroundcolor/i.test(name)) {
      return (function (el) { // get a rgb based color on IE
        var oRG=document.body.createTextRange();
        oRG.moveToElementText(el);
        var iClr=oRG.queryCommandValue("BackColor");
          return "rgb("+(iClr & 0xFF)+","+((iClr & 0xFF00)>>8)+","+
                      ((iClr & 0xFF0000)>>16)+")";
      })(elem);
    }

    return elem.currentStyle[name];
  } else if (elem.style[name]) {
    return elem.style[name];
  } else  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Hopefully soon I'll post a more generic implementation, but this will be enough to solve your `backgorundColor` issue.

You can test the above function [here](http://jsbin.com/ucehe3/2).

Comment: @CMS This is impressive. Can you link to any documentation about return values of getStyle with colors? I am mostly interested in cross-browser issues. Or did you post your finished code somewhere? BTW: the link to the hack gives an error.