# any way to determine transparent background color CSS

Tags: javascript, background-color

there has been plenty written here about determining background colors in javascript, but i haven't seen this question addressed: let's say i have an empty document,  and nothing else, no style. getcomputedstyle for both elements,background-color is "transparent". but what color is that? the user's chosen default, most often white, but could be anything. so there is no way to find out what that is? seems like a flaw in the DOM.

Comment: the effective color depends on the elements underneath.  There may be multiple different background colors over the expanse of a transparent element.

Comment: @Pointy, I might not understood what is being asked here, can you help a bit?

Comment: Its `white` (usually) in case of `body` and other elements take the color of `parent`

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839088/get-real-value-of-a-css-color-property-in-script - according to answers there, the answer is no, there is no way of really knowing what it is.

Comment: @gdoron consider absolute or fixed positioning: for any given pixel of a transparent foreground element, the background depends on what's behind it. It may be possible to look up the DOM through similarly-positioned parents and try to find a non-transparent color, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [tricks this guy used.](http://www.ruzee.com/blog/2006/07/retrieving-css-styles-via-javascript/) Essientally the only way to get a true color is to keep processing parent elements until you find one that provides a color definition.

> The methods above will return 'transparent' when called for the
>   element with the ID someid, with two exceptions:
>
> Safari will return "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)", which means transparent,
>   because the forth value stands for the opacity which is 0. Konqueror
>   3.5 will return "#000000" which is black and which is at the same time a known bug of Konqueror. I've tried to use getPropertyCSSValue, but
>   that one is borked completely...
>
> Now, if you want to retrieve the "real" background color of an
>   element, you have to recursively move up the hierarchy until you find
>   an element that doesn't have a transparent background. You have to
>   stop however at document.body and assume white as background color.

Comment: ... and this technique falls down as soon as elements are positioned with `fixed`, `absolute`, or `relative`.

Comment: @Pointy What in the code would cause the technique to fail on those elements?

Comment: the problem is that just looking at the DOM doesn't tell you what elements are actually positioned behind a transparent element. The element itself could be anywhere on the page, regardless of what the DOM says, and elements that aren't ancestors of the transparent element might be behind it.

Comment: now this method does work *sometimes*, but it's not 100% certain and it's potentially really hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

transparent color is `rgba(0,0,0,0)` . It is any RGB with A=0 i.e. Alpha must be set to 0.